# Read space separated string from file into a single variable

Tags: c

I have a file containing a list of tasks with they status:

```
PENDING Task number 1
COMPLETED Task number 2
COMPLETED Task number 3
```

I'm trying to read this file with:

```
char status[10];
char text[1024];

while(fscanf(file, "%s %s", status, text) != EOF) {
  printf("%s %s\n", status, text);
}
```

However the output is completly wrong. Only the first word of the task text gets to the text variable. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use strtok - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html

Answer (score 0):

```
char status[10];
char text[1024];
char number[1024];
char i[1024];

while(fscanf(file, "%s %s %s %s", status, text, number, i) != EOF) {
  printf("%s %s %s %s\n", status, text, number, i);
}
```

If you know the "number" field is always "number" and you know it's followed by an int,
you can say:

```
char status[10];
char text[1024];
int i;

while(fscanf(file, "%s %s number %d", status, text, i) != EOF) {
  printf("%s %s number %s\n", status, text, i);
}
```

or

```
char line[1000];

while(fgets(line, 1000, file)) {
    char *p;
    for(p = strtok(line, " \n"); p; p = strtok(p, " \n")) {
        printf("%s ", p);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The texts of each task are just an example. They can be anything, nto always 4 words

Comment: Then use fscanf(%s) for each word. Better yet, use fgets() and then strtok()

Answer (score 0):

read line by line into `Buffer` and then using `strtok()` you can split them into words ...

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);

#define MAX_LENGTH 100
File *ptr;
char buffer[MAX_LENGTH]
ptr=fopen("filepath","mode");
while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),ptr)!=EOF)
{
//use strtok  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read a reference such as [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that you can use *sets* as formats, including negative sets that reads while input is not in the set. This means you can do something like

```
if (fscanf(file, "%s %[^\n]s", status, text) == 2)
{
    /* Got all */
}
```

In the format-string `"%s %[^\n]s"`, the first `%s` will read e.g. `"PENDING"`, and the second format-string `%[^\n]s` will read the remaining until newline and so it should be `"Task number 1"`.